# sts.assumeRole getting undefined credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, iot

I have a role called awsiotsdk that has full access to iot. I'm trying to get temporary credentials for Connect, Subscribe, and Receive, but my credentials are undefined. What could be the reason for this?

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var sts = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: "2011-06-15" });

const iotpolicy = `{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualStudioCode",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect",
                "iot:Subscribe",
                "iot:Receive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`;

const role = {
  RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::258030452305:role/awsiotsdk",
  Policy: iotpolicy,
  RoleSessionName: "RoleSession1",
};

sts.assumeRole(role, (err, data) => {
  console.log({
    accessKeyId: data.Credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretAcessKey: data.Credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: data.Credentials.sessionToken,
  });
});
```

Output:

```
{
  accessKeyId: undefined,
  secretAcessKey: undefined,
  sessionToken: undefined
}
```

Comment: Is this a client side script? or run in lambda? Do you have any cloudwatch errors?

Comment: Yes, this is on the client side. Where in cloudwatch can I see errors for this?

Comment: Have you tried using a policy in the format (string with escaped quote chars) used in the example in the doc?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRole-property

Comment: Is there an error (check `err`)? Can you log the whole of `data`?

Comment: Oh I just had to capitalize the first letter of the credential variables (data.Credentials.accessKeyId to data.Credentials.AccessKeyId, etc.). But when I run this in my react app, I get `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` even though my config file has the user with permissions to assume the role with the iot policies.